# How do you make a batch file into a cmd comamnd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have written a batch file in my user folder, which I use a lot. Is there any way that I can call it from cmd when I am working in a different folder, without writing out the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location has to be in the system `%PATH%` for it to be executable directly in cmd. You can see the current `%PATH%` by typing in `echo %PATH%` in the cmd.

So you have two options: Either add your script directory to the `%PATH%`, or put your script in a location that is already contained in the `%PATH%`.

To add the directory to `%PATH%`, selecting `System` from the Control Panel, select the 'Advanced' tab, then the 'Environment Variables' button and then find the PATH (user or system) and edit it. Just append ";" to it.

But adding the entire directory can be dangerous as it will let all executables in your script directory be accessible directly from cmd. A better way, in my opinion, is to copy your script to a directory that is already there in `%PATH%`, like `Windows\System32`.

Comment: Thanks! Basically, cmd.exe can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, even on 64-bit computers (which I have). So I put my `(name here).cmd` into `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. I can now run it as `(namehere) param1 param2 etc.`

Comment: Its actually a really bad habit to put stuff into C:\WIndows. Create a new directory, like C:\BIN or C:\users\parallaxbeta\bin, put your script(s) there and add that to the path.